# List of strings to create a new list of strings without quotes?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqoJj.png)

```
crop_list = ['Cotton','Ragi', 'Groundnut', 'Sugarcane', 'Redgram', 'Sunflower', 'Paddy', 'Maize','Jowar']
```

Now each element is DataFrame

```
for a in crop_list:
    vars()[a] = Data[Data['Crop']== a]
```

For next line of codes i might need to create a list manually, i.e. dfs

```
from functools import reduce
dfs =[Cotton,Ragi,Groundnut,Sugarcane,Redgram,Sunflower,Paddy,Maize,Jowar]
df_merged = reduce(lambda a,b: pd.merge(a,b, on='Year'), dfs)
```

so im asking is there any way to get dunamic list:
Expected output:

Another List with same strings without quotes:

```
new_crop_list = [Cotton,Ragi, Groundnut, Sugarcane, Redgram, Sunflower, Paddy,Maize,Jowar]
```

Comment: In what environment would that output be expected, can you add a Tag for the programming language?

Comment: @StefanWuebbe i need that output in python

Comment: Quotes make strings strings. Without quotes they wouldn't be strings but variables

Comment: @mousetail Yes you are right , using for loop i have stored data in the every element of that list, i want a dynamic list with same values

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify that. Also include the code that initializes the stored data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is basically what you meant

```
crop_list = ["'Cotton'","'Ragi'", "'Groundnut'", "'Sugarcane'", "'Redgram'", "'Sunflower'", "'Paddy'", "'Maize'","'Jowar'"]
```

Since without quotes, a string is not a string, if this is the case. You can remove the single quotes from the list using the following code

```
new_list = [ x.replace("'","") for x in crop_list]
```

The above code will remove single quotes from around the values in the list.
The output will look like

```
['Cotton', 'Ragi', 'Groundnut', 'Sugarcane', 'Redgram', 'Sunflower', 'Paddy', 'Maize', 'Jowar']
```

You will still see single quotes in output, since its a list of strings, and the quotes denotes that .

Hope this answers your question

Comment: I need that sigle quotes removed too

Comment: You cant remove that single quote, the single quote is there to denote that the value is a string. You cannot have strings without quotes in Python. Those quote will not exist if you write the list out to file, or use it somewhere else. The single quote is just there to show that the value is a string, and not a variable name

Comment: @Hasssan Jalil Yes strings work that way. But i have stored values in each element of list that using : for a in crop_list:
    vars()[a] = st_newg2[st_newg2['Crop']== a]

Comment: for each element in crop_list: has data, like Cotton has data, Ragi has data like cost of cultivation. each element is kind of DataFrame

Comment: so each element, in crop_list is not a string, but a variable that has data in it ? or is it a key to some other dictionary, where each key has data against it  ?
If its the first, why is it being stored as a string ?

Comment: each element is string but i have used that list to create dataframes using for loop, so each element has become a dataframe now

Comment: sorry for posting an incomplete question, i have edited the question. Please look into it